# work out how much memory a program (in planning) will need

Tags: c++

I am doing a report for a course where I need to plan a c++ game project. Part of the planning is to estimate how much memory the program will need. I am really unsure as to how to go about doig that.

Should I be estimating the number of variable and their types, the number of classes, the number of funcions, the files used for the poject e.g. bitmap files etc... And adding up how much memory all of those combined will use? Am I looking at this completely the wrong way and/or being stupid? Feel free to say!

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As this is a course I guess you need to do this.  But I would consider looking at http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey and if your estimates come nowhere near the platform average(s).  Then move on and get developing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I be estimating the number of variable and their types

Those take only very little space. For what it's worth you may set this number equal to zero (or a small constant).

> the number of classes

Classes and structures are logical, they don't take up actual space in the later program (save for runtime type information, reflection and such, which are negligble). Classes and structures are for the programmer to structure data. But once the compiler is done with them, it's just flat data as anything else.

> the number of functions

irrelevant, because functions as part of the so called program image occupy memory in a different way than variables and buffers. On your typical PC they will be in RAM for execution, yes. But if you were developing your game for a microcontroller, then the functions would be in the read-only flash memory and don't consume any RAM at all.

> the files used for the project e.g. bitmap files etc...

That's more like it. But you also have to look at all the information created dynamically at runtime.

So what you actually have to look at is, how much information will your game place in buffers; either read from files or procedurally generated. For example it's very simple to write a program that creates points on a sphere:

```
struct v3 {
   double x, y, z;
   v3(double x_, double y_, double z_) : x(x_),y(y_),z(z_)
};
std::vector<v3> sphere;
for(int i_phi = 0; i_phi < n_phi; ++i_phi)
for(int i_theta = 0; i_theta < n_theta; ++i_theta) {
    double phi = 2*M_PI * (double)i_phi / n_phi;
    double theta = M_PI * (double)i_theta / n_theta;

    sphere.push_back( v3(
       cos(phi) * sin(theta),
       sin(phi) * sin(theta),
       sin(-M_PI_2 + theta)
    ));
}
```

This program easily compiles to only a few hundred bytes of code. However say I choose n_phi = 10000, n_theta = 10000 then the memory required would be (assuming `sizeof(double)=8`)

```
sizeof(v3) = sizeof(double)*3 = 24 bytes
sizeof(v3) * 10000 * 10000 = 24 * 100 000 000 = 2.4*10^9 bytes
```

I.e. over 2GiB. That's how you should approach this problem: Follow what your program is doing and estimate what amount of data this produces.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual studio, try to explore memory management in diagnostic tool. else you can estimate it manually by calculating size of images, variables, arrays etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is likely going to use memory from

1. Libraries: are all loaded into memory if are not already in memory.
2. Static Storage: arrays, etc.
3. Functions, misused inline functions will heavily increase memory usage, as well as those functions that declare huge constant arrays.

You can mitigate a lot of it by caching data in and out of files, or over the network(at the cost of performance or need to do occasional buffering of course).

Any libraries you include will end up loading their functionality either from start of program via static libaries, or on demand via dynamic libraries.

Even if you use no additional libraries, all those C++/C functions, many of the abstractions, vtables must be stored in memory, and the more things they need to store in your memory, the more memory will be used.

Memory leaks will increase your memory usage as well, as that memory cannot be accessed anymore.

Beyond the theory, you need to research what profilers work for you and learn to use them effectively to measure the information you need(eg memory usage).

It is not unusual to get completely wrong expectation of how much memory your program will need compared to what the measured results are. Unless you are used to most of the situations, I would expect to get surprised occasionally-often.

There's other means but it's difficult to exhaustively go over it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This has been helpful.